# Mapping two arrays to get an array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, maps, javascript-objects

I need help in getting elements in one array and mapping it to elements in an array of arrays to get an array of object in key value pairs
For example:

```
let arr1 = ["ProjectUniqueID","CompanyUniqueID","ClientProjectID"];
let arr2 = [["20-2867451","2","20-2867451",],
            ["05-3134339","1","05-3134339"],
            ["80-8424593","3","80-8424593",],
            ["18-2895279","3","18-2895279"]
            ]



result = [{ ProjectUniqueID: "20-2867451", CompanyUniqueID: "2", ClientProjectID: "20-2867451"},
          { ProjectUniqueID: "05-3134339", CompanyUniqueID: "1", ClientProjectID: "05-3134339"},
          { ProjectUniqueID: "80-8424593", CompanyUniqueID: "3", ClientProjectID: "80-8424593"},
          { ProjectUniqueID: "18-2895279", CompanyUniqueID: "3", ClientProjectID: "18-2895279"}]
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use Object.fromEntries function like this.

```js
let arr1 = ["ProjectUniqueID","CompanyUniqueID","ClientProjectID"];
let arr2 = [["20-2867451","2","20-2867451",],
            ["05-3134339","1","05-3134339"],
            ["80-8424593","3","80-8424593",],
            ["18-2895279","3","18-2895279"]
            ]
let arrObj = [];
arr2.map((element)=>{
  let item = Object.fromEntries(
    arr1.map((el, index) => [el, element[index]])
  );
  arrObj.push(item);
  }
)
console.log(arrObj)
```

Comment: Etsuko thanks, this answer is not hardcoded and perfect

Answer (score 1):

```
let result =[]
arr2.forEach(element => {
    let data = `{${arr1[0]} : ${element[0]}, ${arr1[1]} : ${element[1]}, ${arr1[2]} : ${element[2]} }`
    result.push(data)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop in `arr2`, make a temp object, and try to map the each entry of `arr1` as the key and each element of the current position on the `arr2` as the values for those keys. Finally, push the temp object into an array. For example:

```js
let arrObj = [];
for(let entry of arr2) {
    let obj = {
            [arr1[0]]: entry[0],
            [arr1[1]]: entry[1],
            [arr1[2]]: entry[2],
    };
    arrObj.push(obj);
}
```

This might be a problem if you have a lot of data to loop in